# Database Design SQL and Transition Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an academic assignment in SQL and I need some help arranging transition tables from a larger table schema.
I have been tasked with creating transition tables for the following schema : [Sales Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvJ9c.png)

The question specifically asks:
**Which tables might be considered transition tables in this database design?  Provide the table schemas for the transition tables only.**

I am uncertain about how to approach transition tables for a larger schema. So far I have come up with :

```
TransTable1(ReceiptNumber, Prod_ID, SalesCode)
Primary Key: SalesCode
Foreign Key: ReceiptNumber

TransTable2(Invoice_Number, Item_Number, Prod_ID)
Primary Key: SalesCode
Foreign Key: ReceiptNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

The table Invoice and Invoice_Item can be made into one transition table as well as Inventory_Item and Inventory_Product can be made into one transition table. This is because a trigger statement written on any one of the tables directly affects another. For example, a trigger on Invoice directly affects Invoice_Item. Transition tables can be made read only.

`CREATE TRIGGER Invoice_Trigger
      AFTER UPDATE OF Quantity_Added ON Invoice_Item 
      REFERENCING Invoice_Item AS N_TABLE 
      NEW AS N_ROW 
      FOR EACH ROW 
      WHEN ((SELECT Item_Number FROM N_TABLE) > (*trigger condition comes here*) 
      BEGIN ATOMIC 
        VALUES(INFORM_SUPERVISOR(N_ROW.Item_Number, 
                                 N_ROW.Quantity_Added, 
                                 N_ROW.Invoice_Number)); 
      END`

Comment: Hi Navidk, can you share how you would form the schemas (form, primary / foreign key) for the transition tables?

Answer (score 0):

There are `OLD` and `NEW` record-variables for `FOR EACH ROW`triggers?
Transition tables are the `FOR EACH STATEMENT` equivalents. They're tables with the old and new tuples, so your triggers can see what changed.They're only available on `AFTER` triggers.
[Here is more on transition tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html)

Schemas should be formed in such a way such that we preserve certain dependencies because this improves the efficiency of the database.
I would create a schema in which Invoice and Invoice_Item is in one table since they depend on each other having Invoice_Number as the primary key. Further I would make Inventory_Item and Inventory_Product as one table having Item_Number as the primary key. The data in both these new combined tables can be accessed by using Item_Number.

Comment: Instead of posting another answer, you should be editing your first answer to make it more clear and specific.